# Swype keyboard does not show, after changing to Swype keyboard and locking screen

Tags: swype

Device: Samsung Galaxy Grand
Android: 4.1.2

I downloaded [Swype keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.dtc) and selected it for use. After that, I locked my screen and tried to type my password, but the keyboard is not opening. Now, I can't use my phone.

Comment: Restart your phone (turn it off, turn it on). Then, let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes its happen to me also.But I can deduce that issue can be happen with swype in two cases.

1. if you are running out of RAM then swype will take some time to launch. because as I have seen swype will take more than 30 MB of RAM and it can take more while it have to start.
2. If you have moved your application SD card then it may take some amount of time to launch.

*what actions supposed to do ?*
  If you are running any kind of task killers , set swype to ignore for killing.
keep swype in your Phone memory only.